# Can [Update Needed] be removed without disabling/enabling FileVault?

Tags: macos, filevault, encryption

I have an additional user `[Update Needed]` appear on login screen at every boot, which doesn't affect usability but a bit annoying. I googled for solution, but all of them are just disabling and enabling FileVault again. That would be time-consuming, somewhat harmful to the SSD, and would leave bits of sensitive data unencrypted on the disk. Is there any other way? Like some terminal commands?

Answer (score 1):

If the Mac in question is running OS X 10.8.x or later, you can remove users from the list of FileVault enabled accounts using the **fdesetup remove** command. To remove the account using the username, run the following command:

```
sudo fdesetup remove -user username
```

Successful removal of the account will not produce any additional output.

[image]

If the account being removed is not currently enabled for use with FileVault 2, an error message will be displayed.

[image]

Does the icon you're seeing look like this?

[image]

If it does, this isn't a user account. It's a password directly associated with the disk's encryption. You will need to decrypt in order to get rid of it.

Comment: The problem is that the pseudouser was created prior to the installation of Yosemite by the Disk Utility. So my operating system doesn't actually have this account.

Comment: Even with `sudo fdesetup list`, I have only my own accounts showed up.